# select records with a column with specific value on specific date sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following table:

```
    ColA    ColB    ColC
    1       A       08/22/2013
    2       B       08/22/2013
    3       A       08/28/2013
    4       C       08/28/2013
```

How to select all records but the ones with `ColB='A'` with a date older than today's date `08/28/2013`

Result should be like below:

```
    ColA    ColB    ColC        
    2       B       08/22/2013
    3       A       08/28/2013
    4       C       08/28/2013
```

Comment: What is the datatype of ColC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a WHERE filter with NOT IN to get the result:

```
select cola, colb, colc
from yourtable
where cola not in (select cola
                   from yourtable
                   where colb = 'A'
                     and colc < '2013-08-28');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42f92/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE1 
WHERE  COLB != 'A' 
        OR ( COLB = 'a' 
             AND COLC < '2013-08-28' )
```

A working example is on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b7ff/6).